# Angular material tree checkbox with real example

Tags: angular, checkbox, tree, angular-material, checkboxtree

I've seen almost all examples about how to work with angular material tree checkbox component. for example [official example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tree-checkboxes?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts) and [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tree-structure-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts).
these examples show us a string array structure as a data was bonded. but how can we transform a nested complex object array to this component?

My data structure:

[image]

As you can see the data says to the client  which items of the checkbox must be set as ticked. and 'Id' must be bind to the tree.

When I replace my 'TREE-DATA' with official example 'TREE-DATA', I see the following tree as result.
I suppose  we need to change 'buildFileTree()' or 'transformer()' methods in [official example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tree-checkboxes?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts).
[image]

Angular(7.0.0), Angular Material(6.4.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem and I wrote a sample in [this place](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtuwrl?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts)

How the problem was solved? 
I did some changes in 'buildFileTree()' and 'transformer()' methods. you can see the changes in the following code:

```
buildFileTree(obj: {[key: string]: any}, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
  const item = obj[key];
  const node = new TodoItemNode();
  node.label = obj[key].name;
  node.id = obj[key].id;
  node.isChecked=  obj[key].isChecked;
  node.claimId=  obj[key].claimId;
  node.isPlanType=  obj[key].isPlanType;

  if (item != null) {
    if (typeof item === 'object'  && item.children!= undefined) { 


      node.children = this.buildFileTree(item.children, level + 1);
    } else {
      node.label = item.name;
    }
  }

  return accumulator.concat(node);
}, []);}

  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
const flatNode = existingNode && existingNode.label === node.label
    ? existingNode
    : new TodoItemFlatNode();
flatNode.label = node.label;
flatNode.level = level;
flatNode.id=node.id;
 flatNode.isChecked = node.isChecked;
 flatNode.claimId = node.claimId;
 flatNode.isPlanType = node.isPlanType;
flatNode.expandable = !!node.children;
this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
return flatNode;  }
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, and it initially worked perfectly. However, I encountered an issue when I needed to have certain checkboxes pre-selected by default. In cases where a user attempted to update these fields, I wanted to display the previously selected values as checked checkboxes. I tried to explore methods but no luck found.